# How to check if a ray intersects with a circle in 2D geometry?

Tags: math, vector, game-development, ray, radius

I have a circle with center (X,Y) and Radius R
Also have a ray starting from center of the circle to end point (Xr,Yr)(Otherwise 100 units form center of the circle)

I have another circle situated with center situated at (a,b) and radius c

I need to find if the ray touches the other cicle

Any one please help me with this
[Actual Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R80Nf.jpg)

I tried with vector and circle distance equations but nothing works

Comment: "I tried with vector and circle distance equations", show that as a [mre] here please. "nothing works" please eleaborate with exampels and the results you get with the code from your MRE.

Comment: If it ends at point Xr, Yr then it's not a ray it's a line segment. Rays start at a point and extend infinitely in one direction. Sorry to be pedantic but you'll need to be precise with your terminology when searching for a suitable algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Get unit direction vector of the ray

```
dx = (Xr-Xc)/R
dy = (Yr-Yc)/R
```

and calculate distance from line (containing ray) to the second circle center (using cross product):

```
Dist = Abs((a-Xc)*dy - (b-Yc)*dx)
```

Then compare this distance with second radius, also be sure that ray is directed to circle using scalar product:

```
if (Dist < R2)
    if ((a-Xc)*dx + (b-Yc)*dy > 0)
         intersection exists
```

**Note** - if the second circle might be large,  might occlude the first one etc, we need more complex checking

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I describe the following in the world with `(X,Y)` as the origin.  i.e. all positions are offsetted as

- `(X,Y) <= (0,0)`
- `(Xr,Yr) <= (Xr-X,Yr-Y)`
- `(a,b)<=(a-X,b-Y)`

Here, with a scalar `t`, equation of point of intersection is
`(t*Xr - a)^2 + (t*Yr - b)^2 = c^2`
(means "distance between 2 positions `t*(Xr,Yr)` and `(a,b)` equals `c`")

Solving this quadratic equation, you know number of point of intersection and their position.

Then, if the line you said as 'ray' is line segment (range is limited), check if at least one of the obtained points is in range. Else( if 'ray' is ray ), what should be checked is sign of `t` only.